# Program runs fine for 24 minutes and then A generic error in GDI+ occurs

Tags: c#

I've made a program to take a screenshot of a specific window over and over again, and while performing stress tests everything works fine until the 4997th iteration.

I'm guessing there's a leak somewhere within the screenshot portion but I've tried everything to prevent it from happening to no avail.

Here's Screenshot.cs

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle rect);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc,int nWidth,int nHeight);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc,IntPtr hgdiobj);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int DeleteDC(IntPtr hdc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd,IntPtr hdcBlt,UInt32 nFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    public static Bitmap MakeScreenshotOfWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        IntPtr hscrdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
        Rectangle windowRect = new Rectangle();
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref windowRect);
        int width = Math.Abs(windowRect.X - windowRect.Width);
        int height = Math.Abs(windowRect.Y - windowRect.Height);
        IntPtr hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hscrdc, width, height);
        IntPtr hmemdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hscrdc);
        SelectObject(hmemdc, hbitmap);
        PrintWindow(hWnd, hmemdc, 0);
        Bitmap bmp = Image.FromHbitmap(hbitmap);
        DeleteDC(hscrdc);
        DeleteDC(hmemdc);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Here's a snippet of where I call the MakeScreenshotOfWindow function:

```
            using (Bitmap screenShot = Screenshot.MakeScreenshotOfWindow(WindowHandle))
            {
                if (screenShot == null)
                {
                    thumbnailError = "screenShot was null";
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    screenShot.Save($"{Program.thumbnailStorage}\\{assetId}-{assetType}-{t}.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                    screenShot.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Here's the full exception that occurs

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap, IntPtr hpalette)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap)
   at ThumbnailServer.Screenshot.PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd) in C:\Users\darkg\source\repos\ThumbnailServer\ThumbnailServer\Screenshot.cs:line 69
   at ThumbnailServer.ThumbnailGenerator.Click(Int32 t, Int32 assetId, Int32 assetType, String& thumbnailError, Int32 w, Int32 h, Boolean hideSky) in C:\Users\darkg\source\repos\ThumbnailServer\ThumbnailServer\ThumbnailGenerator.cs:line 72
```

Comment: Not your problem, but you don't need the call to `Dispose`. The `using` implicitly adds that.

Comment: Check task manager, go to the details tab and enable the columns for GDI objects and Handles, then see if any of those values balloons out of controls. To enable extra columns, right click on a column header for a tool menu.

Comment: `CreateCompatibleBitmap` may return NULL, then you can get the exception

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yeah it's creating a lot of GDI objects, in 2 minutes there's 1,160+

Comment: You should be disposing all your objects with `using` blocks. For unmanaged objects, put `Delete...` in a `finally` block. You should also check the results from the PInvoke functions for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr DeleteObject(IntPtr hwnd);
```

and then this:

```
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
```